# how to check uploaded file is video and make ensure really video type

Tags: php

Selected file is not notepad file with extension avi, mp4 etc.

I tried this:

```
$file_allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','avi','mp4','wmv','mov','flv','webm','ogv','mp3','m4a','ogg','oga');

$uploaded_filename = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

$file_ext = pathinfo($uploaded_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!in_array($file_ext,$file_allowed) ) 
{    
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this variable for validation

```
$_FILES["attachment"]["type"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this:

```
$file_allowed = array('gif','png' ,'jpg','avi','mp4','wmv','mov','flv','webm','ogv','mp3','m4a','ogg','oga');

$uploaded_filename = $_FILES["attachment"]["type"];

$file_ext = pathinfo($uploaded_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!in_array($file_ext,$file_allowed) ) {
exit;
```

}